# Java 9 migration: read package from two modules

Tags: java, maven, java-9

I'm trying to migrate a project from Java 8 to Java 9. I have created my `module-info.java`, export a package, and require all my dependencies but i have the following error :

```
 [ERROR] module netty.resolver reads package javax.persistence.criteria from both eclipselink and javax.persistence
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: A module is not allowed to read the same package from 2 different modules. Check the following article: https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Split-Packages